# How do you keep the console from closing after the program is done?

Tags: java, jar, console, sleep, pause

How do you keep the console from closing after the program is done in Java?

Comment: Im using IntelliJ IDEA, but I will compile application to jar file

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the last closing brace of the `main()`?

Comment: its dont working. I need code

Comment: Ok, are you running the class in IntelliJ and expecting some output on IntelliJ console? Or you are running the jar using perhaps windows Command prompt?

Answer (score 4):

[`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()) waits until you press a key:

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    in.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I've found:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
scanner.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve this.

- You can request the user for input at the end of your `main` method.
- You can create and start a thread. Deamon threads are automatically closed when your main method finishes. However non-deamon threads will keep your application alive until they are finished.
- Or just call `wait` on an object.

I'm not sure though, why you would want to keep an application alive, if it's not doing anything anymore.

**Using a non-deamon thread:**

```
// example of an application that never closes.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public synchronized void run() {
            for(;;)
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
        }
    }).run();
}
```

**Calling wait on an object:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
    Object o = new Object();
    synchronized (o) {
        o.wait();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Firing empty `Scanner` input at the end of the code works each time, because the scanner waits for user to press ENTER.

```
//to-do your code
Scanner.nextLine();
```

Shame Java does not have inbuilt wait or pause command for the console apps.

EDIT: If you want to construct Scanner, you do it like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
scanner.nextLine();
```

`System.in` is parameter that tells the scanner which input stream to use.

Comment: What String put in Scanner constructor?

Comment: I have code:                                                                                          Scanner pause = new Scanner("");
pause.nextLine(); But I have crash Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found